# How to find out whether the form is not having any element(input,select) in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can i find out the form has no element in jquery/javascript.

```
   <form class="form-horizontal holiday_db_form"></form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$("form.form-horizontal.holiday_db_form").find("input, select").length` to decide whether there's any input or select in the form.

`$("form.form-horizontal.holiday_db_form")` will first target the form in metioned, and `.find("select, input")` will find all `input` and `select` that belongs to the form, and if the length is 0, there's no input or select exist.

```js
console.log($('form#form1').find('input, select').length);
console.log($('form#form2').find('input, select').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1"></form>
<form id="form2">
    <input type="text" id="f2t"/>
   <select id="f2s">
    </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Target the form and use `.length` to count the number of children.  If it returns zero, it's empty.

http://jsfiddle.net/gkhq1cvf/

Answer (score 1):

Just use a single class selector and find the length of `input` and `select` elements using `children` as below:

```
var form=$('.form-horizontal');
if(form.children('input').length)
{
      //Input element present
}
if(form.children('select').length)
{
      //Select element present
}
```